# FlashBlink Service error

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, flash

I'm a beginner in programming but i do my best to explain the problem.
I have a basic flash light app and i wanna add a flash blink service.I want it to be bound to a switchable button on/off.

```js
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;


/**
 * Flash Blink Service
 */
public class FlashBlinkService extends Service
{
    static Camera cam = null;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        flashBlinkRunnable.run();
        return startId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        startFlashBlink();
        stopFlashBlink();
        // flash switch button
    }

    //for simulating flash blink
    Runnable flashBlinkRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            cam = Camera.open();
            Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
            //--->
            handler.post(flashBlinkRunnable);
        }
    };



    //start flash blink light
    public void startFlashBlink()
    {
        flashBlinkRunnable.run();
    }

    //stop flash blink light
    public void stopFlashBlink()
    {
        handler.removeCallbacks(flashBlinkRunnable);
        stopCamera(cam);
    }

    //stop camera
    private void stopCamera(Camera cam)
    {
        if (cam != null)
        {
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(flashBlinkRunnable);
        stopCamera(cam);
    }
}
```

and

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    ImageButton btnSwitch;
    ImageButton btnBlink;
    Parameters params;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private boolean hasFlash;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // flash switch button
        btnSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);
        btnBlink = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBlink);

        // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not
        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if (!hasFlash) {
            // device doesn't support flash
            // Show alert message and close the application
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .create();
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
            alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // closing the application
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
            return;
        }

        // get the camera
        getCamera();

        // displaying button image
        toggleButtonImage();


        // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
        btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isFlashOn) {
                    // turn off flash
                    turnOffFlash();
                } else {
                    // turn on flash
                    turnOnFlash();
                }
            }
        });

    }


    // Get the camera
    private void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(e.getMessage(), "Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error:Application will close! ");
            }
        }
    }


    // Turning On flash
    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }
            // play sound
            playSound();

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;


            // changing button/switch image
            toggleButtonImage();
        }

    }


    // Turning Off flash
    private void turnOffFlash() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }
             //play sound
              playSound();
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isFlashOn = false;

            // changing button/switch image
            toggleButtonImage();
        }
    }
    // Playing sound
    // will play button toggle sound on flash on / off
    private void playSound(){
        if(isFlashOn){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.soundonclick);
        }else{
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.soundonclick);
        }
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        mp.start();
    }



    /*
     * Toggle switch button images
     * changing image states to on / off
     * */
    private void toggleButtonImage() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.poweronline);
        } else {
            btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.poweroffline);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // on pause turn off the flash
        turnOffFlash();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        // on resume turn OFF the flash
        if (hasFlash)
            turnOffFlash();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // on starting the app get the camera params
        getCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // on stop release the camera
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }


    // Method to start the service
    public void startService(View view) {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), FlashBlinkService.class));
    }

    // Method to stop the service
    public void stopService(View view) {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), FlashBlinkService.class));
    }


}
```

When i run the application and press on one of the flash blink button it says that my app stopped working and the flash blink starts randomly.

What's wrong with the code and what i should write further?

PS: Logcat

```js
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight.FlashBlinkService: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2608)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:154)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1372)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:410)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:383)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight.FlashBlinkService$1.run(FlashBlinkService.java:45)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight.FlashBlinkService.startFlashBlink(FlashBlinkService.java:65)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight.FlashBlinkService.onCreate(FlashBlinkService.java:35)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2598)
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:154) 
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1372) 
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306) 
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
10-14 18:21:58.266 8459-8459/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:

```js
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight.FlashBlinkService: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2608)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:154)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1372)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight.FlashBlinkService$1.run(FlashBlinkService.java:45)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight.FlashBlinkService.startFlashBlink(FlashBlinkService.java:66)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight.FlashBlinkService.onCreate(FlashBlinkService.java:35)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2598)
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:154) 
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1372) 
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306) 
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
10-16 14:44:25.761 19688-19688/com.example.gothi.yourbfflashlight E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There is a stack trace in the logcat output. Show it please.

Comment: @ci_  i've added it!Hope you can help me =]

Comment: You `open()` the camera in your `Activity` and then you also try to `open()` the camera in your `Service` without releasing the camera first, You can't do that. You can only have one open instance of the camera at any given time.

Comment: @ci_ , Hi!I added a new logcat.